# Get all files located on a server?

Tags: web, dns

I'm trying to find all of the (javascript) resources located on a specific site.

What would be a efficient way of finding them?

Everything I could think of is bruteforcing every possible name and check whether there's a file with this name at the server, although this isn't exactly that efficient.

Comment: If you don't have access to the server, and the server doesn't expose the filenames (e.g. directory listing), it's not possible. Not even by bruteforcing. "Not exactly efficient" doesn't even begin to describe it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this. The thing which you actually want to do is web directory traversal.. 

It is a kind of web vulnerability which is usually taken in to consideration by the web master so you get 403-Forbidden or 404-Not Found Error. Manual exploitation on this is surely possible with trial and error basis in case u get to know directory that contains .js files. 
For automation You can take use of Python/Perl for ease of use. I am personally working on a same project targeting the same objective using PHP and cURL. At very present I can not help about any source code but for sure I'll be posting same.